# Particle system, hair curves, or geometry nodes for grass to get lowest processor strain?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm starting my environment for an archvis project that will be animated in EEVEE. Later I'll be creating environments for other animated projects with characters. I've been trying out different grass generators, which seem to use a particle system, as well as the hair curves feature in 3.6. The hair curves give me better control and I'd have to create a shader to correctly color, not a super big deal there but, as I am animating the project, which would put less strain on a processor; particle system, hair curves, or geometry nodes? I have a pretty healthy desktop, i7, 64gb RAM, multiple SSD's, and a RTX 3090...I just don't want to stretch out rendering any longer than necessary. I haven't tried geometry nodes for grass yet and spend an entire day working with various addon generators and am wondering at what point I'm chasing my own tail and need to focus on one...just which one?

Comment: I think it's secondary how much of a load it puts on the CPU. Primarily, I would ask myself how I can get the animation done. It depends on the scene, the animation, and the GN experience. The (old) hair particle system supports Dynamic Hair with physics simulation, meaning you can use a wind force field and create grass swaying in the wind relatively easily. The simulation data can be baked.

Comment: In contrast, the (new) *curves* can only be animated with GN so far (Blender 4.0) and only with Simulation Nodes the data can be baked. I have no idea how this affects render time, but I think animating grass in GN is more challenging than with the old particle system for now. In the long run, Curves+GN are the future, while the old particle system is basically at the end of its life.

Comment: Thanks, So, with 4.0 around the corner, we stand with one foot in the past and one in the future....like most software. I took a scene, added a yard with grass made with curves and my render time, in EEVEE, was about three and a half minutes for a frame...a bit longer than I want. Of course, I hadn't baked it, just a quick test. I'll keep running some experiments.